# C++ vector constructor implementation

Tags: c++, vector

How do I make it possible to call the following construct for my vector class?

```
vector <int> v{1,2,3};
```

how to properly declare such a method?

My source code:

```
template<typename T>
class my_vector {
    T* values;
    std::size_t values_num;
    std::size_t max_size;

    public:
        explicit my_vector(std::size_t size);
        ~my_vector();

        void push_back(const T& value);
        std::size_t size();
        T operator[](int pos);
        T at(int pos);
};
```

Comment: use std::initializer_list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Another way is writing a template constructor, a bit like this:

```
template<class...Ts> requires (std::is_same_v<T, Ts> && ...)
explicit my_vector(Ts...ts);
```

but getting that just right is a pain, so just go with `initializer_list`.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is also more flexible by allowing conversions to `T`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You can write a template constructor that permits conversions to T.  But you don't want to be too generous either.  Like I said, doing it just right is a pain; I just sketched out a simple one.

Comment: On that note, `std::initializer_list` forces you to copy elements, and it doesn't work with move-only types.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili You can work around that with a bit of wrapping, and that is easier than writing a correct template constructor replacement.  Or even have a ctor taking an array.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont how would you work around that, short of a const cast?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Use mutable, not a const cast, and a wrapper type.